# How to append Divs dynamically side by side using javascript using loops?

Tags: javascript

Can you please help how to append Divs side by side using javascript using loops,
here two columns and 6 rows.
I tried the following code,

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {
        document.write('<div style="width:200px;height=200px;border:1px solid red;float:left" />')+"\n";    
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this moar of a CSS issue rather than a JS issue? Also please don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: it works - http://jsfiddle.net/h3NMn/

Comment: Maybe you should be using a table?

Comment: That would produce two rows and four columns, but the way it is written [minus the \n error] it would be one row until it wraps in the browser.

Comment: @ZoltanToth try to change resolution ..

Comment: This is a really good example of how to not write this code to be flexible & unobtrusive.  Check out a CSS framework (e.g. TwitterBootstrap) and let your code write out classnames instead of all that style tag crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
​<div id="table"></div>​
```

js:

```
var newdiv;
for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<6;j++) {
        newdiv=document.createElement("div");
        newdiv.style.width = '80px';
        newdiv.style.height = '80px';
        newdiv.style.border = '1px solid red';
        newdiv.style.float = 'left';
        document.getElementById('table').appendChild(newdiv);    
    }
    newdiv=document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.style.clear = 'both';
    document.getElementById('table').appendChild(newdiv);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added the `"\n"` at wrong place.

```
 document.write('<div style="width:200px;height=200px;border:1px solid red;float:left" />'+"\n");
```

**Tested code**:-

```
function CreateDiv()
{
for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {
            document.write('<div style="width:200px;height=200px;border:1px solid red;float:left" >Hi</div>');  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/DsqMj/4/

HTML

```
<div id="table"></div>
```

CSS

```
#table .box {
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #ccc;
}
#table .box:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #eee;
}
#table .col {
width:100px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
float: left;
}
```

JS

```
makeTable();

function makeTable() {
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row ='';

for(var i=0;i<2;i++) 
{    
    for(var j=0;j<6;j++) 
    {
        row += "<div class='box'></div>";
    }
    table.innerHTML += "<div class='col'>"+row+"</div>";
    row ='';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems working, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/fCSTp/1/

```
var i = 0, div,
    node = document.createElement("div"),
    main = document.getElementById("main");

while (6 > i++) {
    div = node.cloneNode(true);
    div.innerHTML = i;
    div.style.cssText = "width:200px;height:20px;float:left;border:1px solid red";
    main.appendChild(div);
}

delete node;
delete div;
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert a `<br style="clear:both"/>` at the end of each row:

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<5;j++) {
        document.write('<div style="width:200px;height=200px;border:1px solid red;float:left" />')+"\n";    
    }
    document.write('<br style="clear:both"/>');
}
```